# Display Boolean Field in Visual Studio Report Designer

Tags: sql-server, reporting-services

I'm trying to display a boolean field in Report Designer in Visual Studio 2008. When I tried to run it, an error occurred:

```
  "An error has occurred during report processing.
      String was not recognized as a valid Boolean."
```

I tried to convert it using CBool() but it didn't work.

Comment: A little bit mroe info is needed. I assume this is client side report with your own datasource? If so what type is on the DS? What type of field are you putting it into in the report?

Answer (score 3):

```
=iif(Fields!YourBool.Value, "True", "False")
```

Am I missing anything?

Comment: One thing to watch if you are doing something like `=iif(Fields!YourBool.Value, "Yes", "No")` is that NULLs are returned as 'No'. If you want to honour NULLs properly: `=iif(isnothing(Fields!YourBool.Value), nothing, iif(Fields!YourBool.Value, "Yes", "No"))` which is really long and verbose!! (alt - modify the sql query)

Answer (score 1):

I may be mistaken here, but CBool is to convert to boolean.  What you probably want is to convert to string so that it can be displayed.  However, I'm not sure what the default behaviour would be (i.e. 0/1, true/false, -1/0, Yes/No, etc.) so you could add a function to the code section in the report to display a boolean the exact way you want.

Answer (score 0):

I'm using SQL Server 2005. The data type is bit.